# Is prisma ORM an API?

Tags: api, prisma

I have been trying to clarify the definition of API, form my understanding, API is any kind of services that act like middleman when two applications( such as web framework and database ) cannot talk each other directly.
And I think prisma is one of API, am I correcly understanding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An API is an **Application Programming Interface**.

Originally, typically specified how an application invoked functionality in a programming library. Later, the term was generalized to mean other things: for example, specifying how an HTTP-based application must interact with a REST service.

From Wikipedia:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API
>
> An application programming interface
> (API) is a way for two or more computer programs to communicate with
> each other. It is a type of software interface, offering a service to
> other pieces of software.[1]

To answer your question:

- [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) is an ORM
- Prisma has an API.  Prisma client apps use the [Prisma API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference) to interact with the underlying database.

Comment: Great answer! The term API is so ambiguous these days and indeed most of the time used in the context of the web when people refer to HTTP-based APIs. But Prisma Client indeed also has an API, and so does (pretty much) any other library that you install via npm.